# What does paint mean in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

looking at the resource tracking in chrome. There is a lot of purple instance called

```
Paint (179x40)
```

and then when you hover over it it says

```
Re-calculated style - details
Duration 0 (at 7.14s)
Used Heap size 8.77mb of 11.37mb
```

And there are hundreds of them. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Based on how most GUI programs work, that is the function used to redraw the screen. Any time anything changes on the screen in a GUI program, Paint() is called. I assume that Chrome is following a similar paradigm.

Comment: So, since there are literally hundreds of these Paint instances, the screen could possibly be redrawing every time?

Comment: @Tim Joyce, absolutely. GUI programs repaint the screen tens of thousands of times.

Comment: @Stargazer712 - Not just according to the display frequency? (seriously asking)

Comment: @Rook, depends. If you're talking about how often the pixels on the screen *actually refresh*, then we're talking about operating system stuff. From a programmer's standpoint, Paint in a GUI program is invoked anytime that the screen is invalidated. This can happen because either a)The window was resized b)the user interacted with a control that invalidated the screen, or c)you manually invalidate the screen. For example, if you have an animation on the screen, you would probably invalidate the screen 24 times per second, thus redrawing everything and making paint get called very frequently.

Comment: @Stargazer712 - Yes, but in no cases it needs to be called more often than the value of freq. of display. Or have I misunderstood (what would be the point?) ?

Comment: @Stargazer712 - Stargazer, Can you submit that as an answer so I can accept it? It makes sense, and since you have put it on the internet it has to be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on how most GUI programs work, that is the function used to redraw the screen. Any time anything changes on the screen in a GUI program, Paint() is called. I assume that Chrome is following a similar paradigm.